# Groovy/Spock BUG! when passing variable into closure

Tags: groovy, spock

I have a Spock test of this form:

```
def "test"() {
    when:
        List result = repo.getSomeData(devices)

    then:
        result.size() == 1
        interaction {
            containsRequiredKeys(result[0].keySet())
        }

    where:
        devices | _
        id1     | "devices provided"
        null    | "no devices provided"
}
```

When running this I get the following error when compiling:

```
Error:Groovyc: BUG! exception in phase 'class generation' in source unit 'D:\w\traffic-data-web-service\src\integrationTest\groovy\com\company\project\db\Test.groovy' tried to get a variable with the name result as stack variable, but a variable with this name was not created
at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.CompileStack.getVariable(CompileStack.java:288)
at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.ClosureWriter.loadReference(ClosureWriter.java:131)
at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.ClosureWriter.writeClosure(ClosureWriter.java:106)
at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitClosureExpression(AsmClassGenerator.java:657)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ClosureExpression.visit(ClosureExpression.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.CallSiteWriter.makeCallSite(CallSiteWriter.java:303)
at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeCachedCall(InvocationWriter.java:307)
at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeCall(InvocationWriter.java:392)
at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeCall(InvocationWriter.java:104)
at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeInvokeMethodCall(InvocationWriter.java:88)
at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.writeInvokeMethod(InvocationWriter.java:459)
at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitMethodCallExpression(AsmClassGenerator.java:767)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.MethodCallExpression.visit(MethodCallExpression.java:66)
at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeExpressionStatement(StatementWriter.java:607)
at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeExpressionStatement(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:357)
at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitExpressionStatement(AsmClassGenerator.java:620)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ExpressionStatement.visit(ExpressionStatement.java:42)
at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeBlockStatement(StatementWriter.java:84)
at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeBlockStatement(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:158)
at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitBlockStatement(AsmClassGenerator.java:566)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement.visit(BlockStatement.java:71)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClassCodeContainer(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:104)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitConstructorOrMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:115)
at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitStdMethod(AsmClassGenerator.java:430)
at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitConstructorOrMethod(AsmClassGenerator.java:387)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:126)
at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitMethod(AsmClassGenerator.java:507)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.visitContents(ClassNode.java:1086)
at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClass(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:53)
at org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitClass(AsmClassGenerator.java:233)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$16.call(CompilationUnit.java:813)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1055)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:591)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:569)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:546)
at org.jetbrains.groovy.compiler.rt.GroovyCompilerWrapper.compile(GroovyCompilerWrapper.java:62)
at org.jetbrains.groovy.compiler.rt.DependentGroovycRunner.runGroovyc(DependentGroovycRunner.java:115)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.jetbrains.groovy.compiler.rt.GroovycRunner.intMain2(GroovycRunner.java:134)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.groovy.InProcessGroovyc.runGroovycInThisProcess(InProcessGroovyc.java:156)
at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.groovy.InProcessGroovyc.access$000(InProcessGroovyc.java:51)
at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.groovy.InProcessGroovyc$1.call(InProcessGroovyc.java:85)
at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.groovy.InProcessGroovyc$1.call(InProcessGroovyc.java:82)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or is it an actual bug with Spock or Groovy?
If it helps, I've got the following in my build.gradle:

```
compile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.4"
testCompile "org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4"
testCompile "org.spockframework:spock-spring:1.0-groovy-2.4"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `interaction` use the variable `result`. Spock can't match the interaction during the test, because result is initialized after the invocation of `repo.getSomedata`

under the hood, interaction (mocks) are moved (initialized) before `when` clauses (where `result` is undefined)

Comment: That explains why I'm getting the error, but is there an alternative that you would suggest? Or is the `interaction {}` really intended for working with Mocks?

Comment: The documentation have a section on exactly that issue: [link](https://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.0/interaction_based_testing.html#_explicit_interaction_blocks)

In your case, I can't see why you should need the interaction closure

Comment: Was just looking at that myself, their example works with a mock though

Comment: yes, "interaction" block is for mocks : it permit to move a full 'block' before when clauses, and not only a mock interaction

Comment: Thanks for the info, I ended up just making a list of all expected keys and doing `result[0].keySet().containsAll(expectedKeys)` without the `interaction {}`